# Which one will be invoked first? doHeader or doView

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, portlet

When hitting a portet in the view mode which method will be invoked first by the portlet container..? will it be doHeader or doView..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **default implementation** of method `render` of `javax.portlet.GenericPortlet` calls at first `doHeaders` and than `doDispatch`, which calls `doView`.

Edit1:
You can see the source at [grepcode.com](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/javax.portlet/com.springsource.javax.portlet/2.0.0/javax/portlet/GenericPortlet.java#GenericPortlet.render%28javax.portlet.RenderRequest%2Cjavax.portlet.RenderResponse%29)
Or just decompile the class GenericPortlet from [portlet-api-2.0.jar](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/root_repository/maven2/javax/portlet/portlet-api/2.0/)

Comment: could you provide me the source from which you got the information..? will this be in the portlet spec..?